# Extract first and last column from text file

Tags: unix

I have a text file, I only want the first column and the last column.  However the problem is they are separated by both whitespace and tabs at random places, making it hard for me to use `cut`

```
USER02163 name BAD
USER5415 ab lsi ei GOOD
USER15356 sl oe ow BAD
```

Desired output is:

```
USER02163 BAD
USER5415 GOOD
USER15356 BAD
```

Does anyone have a hacky way I can get my desired output?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Easiest by using `awk`.  The command is:

```
awk '{print $1, $NF}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

**When you specify field separator as space in awk it will include single and multiple spaces. So you can use like this,**

```
awk -F " " '{print $1,$NF}' file
```

Same as unxnut answer. Added with field separator which gives clear insight.

Answer (score 1):

Use this sed command

```
$ sed -r 's/([^ ]*) (.*) (.*$)/\1  \3/' filename
```

The output is :

```
   USER02163  BAD
   USER5415  GOOD
   USER15356  BAD
```